# Remove the button when user clicks font awesome icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This may seem a very stupid question but I cant get my head around it. I want this button with email in it to be removed when user clicks font awesome(x) icon. Basically, I want the emails added to be removed.

```
<div id="closes">
    <button class="btn btn-sm ">
        <span> email@email.com.net</span>
        <a href="#" onclick="myFunction()">
            <span class="fa fa-times-circle close"></span>
        </a>
    </button>
</div>
```

I know almost nothing about jquery, but from search this is the best I could gather.

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        $(this).closest('span').closest('button').closest('div').remove();
    }
</script>
```

work done till now is given in this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/4mkwn0ad/6/).

Comment: the email must to be button

Comment: Can you please expand  on this. Do you mean I should remove <span>.

Comment: see my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need [`event.preventDefault();`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent from default behavior. Since your close is inside the `a` tag, it will try to navigate to that page. And to remove `button` which contain email simply you can use `$(this).parents('button')` because your button is in parent of the clicked element. [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) get the ancestors of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```js
$('.closes').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parents('button').remove();

});
```

```css
@import url(https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css);
@import url(https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css);
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    display: inline - block;
}


.close {
    position: absolute;
    margin - right: 0;
    margin - top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper closes">
    <button class="btn btn-sm ">
        <span>email@email.com.net</span>
        <a href="">
            <span class="fa fa-times-circle close"></span>
        </a>
    </button>
</div>
<div class="wrapper closes">
    <button class="btn btn-sm ">
        <span>email@email.com.net</span>
        <a href="">
            <span class="fa fa-times-circle close"></span>
        </a>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: This one worked as well. And thanks for pointing out the drawback of anchor tag over here.

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow. Can you show me how to do that. Never mind, clicked the tick.

Comment: Mate, if i create two buttons in two different div, I cant close the second button.  http://jsfiddle.net/scvj2z0w/3/

Comment: @Gambit id cannot be duplicate.

Comment: @Gambit update you `id` to `class`. I have done it in my above snippet. Check it once. And if it works don't forget to mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to set Ids for all the HTML elements you  want to perform some action using javascript/jquery. That helps to get the correct element.

After that write the onClick event on the font awesome icon and remove the button in that method.

HTML:

```
    <div id="closes" class="wrapper">
      <button id="button" class="btn btn-sm ">
         <span>email@email.com.net</span>&nbsp;
           <a class="fa fa-times-circle close" id="icon"></a>
         </button>
    </div>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#icon").click(function(){
         $("#button").remove();
       });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4mkwn0ad/29/

Answer (score 0):

Use `remove()` to `button` not `div`

```
function myFunction() {
   $(this).closest('span').closest('button').remove();
}
```

Comment: tell me if that what you mean

Comment: Basically its the user email. and if that user doesn't want notification to be received , he will remove it. And hide() doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Make it simple, assign an id to the email span like

```
<span id="email-text">email@email.com.net</span>
```

then inside your `myFunction` do something like

```
$('#email-text').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to use `ID` instead of function then you need to change `anchor` tag to `span` because when click on `anchor` tag then page refresh.

You can use like below code its working fine:-

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="closes">
            <button class="btn btn-sm ">
                <span>email@email.com.net</span>
                <span href="" id="anchorTag">
                    <span class="fa fa-times-circle close">X</span>
                </span>
            </button>
        </div>
        
         <script>
             $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#anchorTag').click(function(){
       $(this).closest('span').closest('button').closest('div').remove();
    })
                 });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.btn-sm a').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('button').remove();
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div id="closes">
  <button class="btn btn-sm ">
    <span>email@email.com.net</span>
      <a href="#">
        <span class="fa fa-times-circle close"></span>
      </a>
  </button>
</div>
```